# Meaning of "over" in the context—

Tags: prepositions

The victory **over** the French at Waterloo was Wellington's greatest triumph.

What is the meaning of **over** here?

Comment: It's just a metaphorical use of spatial position, same as you might ***win someone over*** to your opinion, by persuasive argument. Or *be **under** attack*, or *have **the down** on* someone you feel negatively towards. Or ***beat someone up***, I suppose, but you're still the winner if you ***beat them down***. In your cited context, ***against*** would be a drop-in replacement for ***over***, but that doesn't mean ***over = against*** here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, "over" is just a preposition that *correlates* with "victory" to indicate the party that had a loss.

It doesn't have any particular meaning, but it's reasonable to assume somewhere, way back in the history of Germanic languages, it was chosen because it also has the meaning of "above" or "higher than", which we commonly associate with winners as compared to losers.

So as far as learning English goes, you just have to remember that "over" has this function when used with "victory" and other words that generally mean "win".

Comment: One exception comes to mind, and reinforces my comment that ***against** would be a drop-in replacement for **over**, but that doesn't mean **over = against here.*** A woman might say *It was **nice** to have two men fighting **over** me!* OR *It was **awful** to have two men fighting **against** me!* Switching the prepositions there would create unlikely utterances!

Comment: Both prepositions "against" and "over" can be used with this same function. This has no bearing on the meanings of over and against, nor on other functions of "over" in correlation with other verbs or nouns.

Comment: Traditionally, the winner of a fight would be the one standing, while the defeated opponent would be kneeling, knocked down, or lying dead/injured. I suspect the idea that the winner would be higher than the loser probably predates writing.